# Передать параметр в функцию через структуру

Tags: c++

Как можно передать параметр в функцию через структуру? Есть код:

```
void function(Help h) {
    getF(par, set);
}

void getF(par, set) {
    ///
}

struct Help {
    int par;
    const int set;
}

int main {
    int par = 3;
    const int set = 4;
    function(h);
    return 0;
}
```

Т.е. в `function` нужно как-то закинуть `set`. Но не добавляя его в параметры, т.е. так: `void function(int par, int set)`

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, сделать структуру, которая будет играть роль контейнера параметров?

Comment: VladD, да, если я правильно понял

Comment: А в чём проблема? Заведите структуру с двумя полями.

Comment: Обновил, а что теперь?

Comment: Теперь пусть функция принимает на вход `Help h` (только с const по идее не скомпилируется).

Comment: Обновил. А как тогда с const сделать? Мне просто const обязательно нужно, т.к. это размер массива.

Comment: Например, сделайте поле `set` приватным, и выдавайте значение через функцию `getSet()`. Но в принципе можно не заморачиваться, т. к. всё равно в функцию придёт _копия_ вашей структуры, а не оригинал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

читайте комментарии в коде

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct theParameters{ // Создаем новый тип который
    int a;            // мы будем передавать в функцию
    int b;            // в качестве параметров.
};

void PrintParameters(theParameters p){ // Функция будет принимать
    cout << p.a << endl;               // theParameters в качестве
    cout << p.b << endl;               // единого параметра.
}

int main(){
    theParameters parameters; // Cоздали экземпляр.

    parameters.a = 10; // Заполнили
    parameters.b = 13; // значениями.

    PrintParameters(parameters); // Передали как параметер и напечатали значения экземпляра

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Или так: `theParameters parameters { 10, 13 };`. http://ideone.com/ox19Z3 ([документация](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization))

Comment: Или даже так:  `PrintParameters((theParameters){20, 33}); // Передали как параметер и напечатали новые значения`

Comment: @avp: Правда? Не знал.

Comment: @avp, приведение типа не нужно. Достаточно `PrintParameters({20, 33});`

Comment: @ixSci, ага, оказываеся в 11-м (-std=gnu++11) уже не нужно. Вообще-то, да, приводить к типу приемника это разумно. А я все по старинке (кстати, дефолтный g++ в Ubuntu по умолчанию без -std... такое не берет)

Comment: @avp, да это нововведение 11 года.

Answer (score 2):

Современный C++ позволяет избежать явного создания вспомогательных структур, единственное предназначение которых состоит в том, чтобы упаковать вместе несколько параметров:

**(Осторожно, C++14!)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

void func(int one, double two) {
    cout << one << ", " << two << endl;
}

void func(int one, double two, string three) {
    cout << one << ", " << two << ", " << three << endl;
}

void func(int one, string three) {
    cout << one << ", " << three << endl;
}

// Начало шаблонной магии
template <typename... Args, size_t... I>
void func_invoker(tuple<Args&...> args, index_sequence<I...>) {
    func(get<I>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void func_helper(tuple<Args&...> args) {
    func_invoker(args, index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
// Конец шаблонной магии

int main()
{
    int one = 1;
    double two = 2.0;
    string three = "3";

    func_helper(tie(one, two));
    func_helper(tie(one, two, three));
    func_helper(tie(one, three));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что не спрашивал. Но это как бы напрашивается само собой.

Comment: Попробуйте. Возможно, это кому-то будет интересно.

Comment: Почему не надо? Это же база знаний. Любой вопрос - это просто повод для того, чтобы рассказать что-нибудь интересное в формате ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
class local_set
{
friend void getF(int _par, local_set & _set);...

public:
  ...
  void func(int _par)
  { getF(_par, *this);
    }

  };
```

...

```
void getF(int _par, local_set & _set)
{ ........
  }
```

...

```
int main()
{   local_set Set(); // тут будет ругаться на отсутсвие конструктора, его описывают в секции public

    Set.up(4); // тут(и ниже) будет ругаться на отсутсвие метода up
    Set.up(3);
    Set.func(3);
    return (0);
    }
```